# Range of epsilon and alpha parameter in SVM and elastic net for hyperparameter optimization

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, svm

I want to do regression with around 500 data points. For that I would like to use epsilon-SVM (`sklearn.svm.SVR`) with a RBF kernel. The true labels I would like to predict are discrete value from 1 to 9.

The epsilon-SVM has the parameter epsilon which I would like to optimize using random search.

What range of values should I try for epsilon?

For example for the parameter C I'm using `scipy.stats.expon(scale=100)` and for the gamma parameter `scipy.stats.expon(scale=.1)`.

Second, I would also like to use elastic net (`sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet`). What range (or distribution) should I choose for the `alpha` parameter?